# htaccess URL prettifying: preserving non-html/php paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to present all of my .html and .php files as directory paths, such that

www.domain.com/path/page.html will appear as www.domain.com/path/page/.

My feeble attempts, based on a few hours of searching and reading - EDIT: Made a couple of changes that changed the behavior.

```
# Rewrite to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^(\S+\/)*(\S+)\.html$ $1$2/
```

The first rule now redirects http://www.domain.com/index.html to http://www.domain.com/index/, which is the desired behavior. 
The second rule, when enabled, results in a 500 response.

```
# Redirect to actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(\S+\/)*(\S+)\/$ $1$2.html
```

The first rule attempts to match the entire path and then the file, rewriting it to directory format.

The second attempts to read the directory format and send it to the appropriate file. I'm dying. Neither is working, and I'm just lost.

Edit: when I navigate directly to the folder format, it does something, but adds /index/ to all of the requests for css, js, and img resources as well, so it looks wrong.  It also adds /index/ to all links on the page, which results in a 404...

EDIT: Here's my full htaccess file for reference. Nothing too out of the ordinary.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirects requests for my images to a bad image
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.+\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|jpg)$ /image/catalog/theft_prevention.jpe [L]

# Redirects non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# serve custom error pages
ErrorDocument 400 /error-400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error-401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error-403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.html
ErrorDocument 410 /error-410.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error-500.html

# Rewrite to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^(\S+\/)*(\S+)\.html$ $1$2/ [R=301, L]

# Redirect to actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(\S+\/)*(\S+)\/$ $1$2.html [R=301, L]
```

Comment: The regex in the first rule looks correct to me ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zY0uW8/1)).  What is not working and are you sure that your application can handle paths?

Comment: I'm using a simple HTML template. The second rule is meant to handle the paths.  I actually used regex101 to test both rules.